# Python descending list

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I want to make a functions which return false if the list input in the function is not in descending order ,

now for descending([19,17,18,7]) it returns true

i don't know why for some reason it is exiting out of if statement and printing true every time.

```
def des(l):
    for i in range(len(l)):
            if (l[i]<l[i+1]):
                return [False,i]
            else:
                return True
```

Comment: This doesn't give a index out of range error? it seems like it should..

Comment: Please provide a short, **complete** program that demonstrates the error. Your program a) never calls `des()`, and b) never prints *anything*. See [mcve] for more information.

Comment: Also, it isn't clear what you question is. Do you have a specific question to ask?

Comment: ...I acutally see the error... `return True` should only occur after the for loop terminates successfully without ever returning false.

Answer (score 3):

It can be written in a more declarative way:

```
def is_descending(array):
    return array == sorted(array, reverse=True)
```

Or, for python3:

```
def is_descending(array):
    return array == list(sorted(array, reverse=True))
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesn't work because you are returning `True`/`False` after one check. You should return `True` only after you check the entire list. Following is one way of doing it:

```
def des(l):
    for i in range(1,len(l)):
        if (l[i] > l[i-1]):
            return False
    return True

l = [19,17,12,10]


print (des(l))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to write your function:

```
def des(l):
    return all(i>j for i,j in zip(l,l[1:]))
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you only ever make one check, and always *immediately* return `True` or `False`.

Instead, you shouldn't be returning `True until you have checked the whole list:

```
def des(l):
    for i in range(len(l)):
        if (l[i]<l[i+1]):
            return [False,i]
    return True
```

This will give you another problem, however:

```
>>> des([4,3,2,1])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in des
IndexError: list index out of range
```

This is because when you get to the last value in your `range`, you look at a value beyond the end of the list.  The easiest way to fix that is to subtract one from your range:

```
def des(l):
    for i in range(len(l) - 1):
        if (l[i]<l[i+1]):
            return [False,i]
    return True
```

In python, it's generally bad practice to use `range(len(...))`.  A better option is [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=enumerate#enumerate), which returns a sequence of `(index, value)` pairs, but that doesn't solve the above problem:

```
def des(l):
    for i, v in enumerate(l):
        if (v < l[i+1]):
            return [False,i]
    return True
```

This still has the IndexOutOfRange error.  We can fix that by pretending the list we're iterating over is one shorter:

```
def des(l):
    for i, v in enumerate(l[:-1]):
        if (v < l[i+1]):
            return [False,i]
    return True
```

And there you have a much more "pythonic" (i.e. in the style a python expert would do) solution.

There is one other unpythonic problem with this code: if you do `if des(my_list)): ...`, it won't work.  This is because a non-empty `list` (what you're creating using the `[]` in the return statement, is *always* truthy.

If you want to get the index of the ascending item, there's not really any way round that, but it should be made clearer in the function name.

Also, you can't do

```
is_descending, bad_index = des(...)
```

Because you just return `True` on success.  Better would be

```
def des(l):
    for i, v in enumerate(l[:-1]):
        if (v < l[i+1]):
            return (False,i)
    return (True, None)
```

Note also that I'm using parentheses to group my result pairs, this creates a new `tuple`.  In general, `list`s should be used if *all* of the members represent the same thing, `tuple` should be used if the members represent *different* things, such as in this case, they represent a *result*, and *where the failure occurred*.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
def des(l):
    for x in l:
        try:
            if x < l[l.index(x)+1 ]-1:
                return True
        except:
            pass
    return False
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

```
def des(l):
    for i in range(len(l)):
        if (l[i]<l[i+1]):
            return [False,i]

    return True
```

You return True if its not false, You must only return true when the entire for loop has run through. Therefore it must be outside the for loop. If once the loop has run through and nothing has been returned, then return True